# Listen to keyboard input in GLFW and modify objects accordingly?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, opengl-compat

I'm trying to draw a pyramid in cpp. I have managed to implemented the input handler and the rendering function, but it seems any change on my pyramid is overwritten by the initial state. (that is to say, despite being able to accept input and move the object, the object always "jump back" to its initial position and angle)

My codes are like this:

```cpp
void listenToKeyboard(GLFWwindow* w) {
    if (glfwGetKey(w, GLFW_KEY_F) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f); // move forward
        posArr1[2] -= 0.1f;
    }

void drawPyramid(GLfloat p[][3]) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    // some drawing functions like glVertex3f
    ...codes...
    glEnd();
}

void renderPyramidWithInput(GLFWwindow* w, GLfloat p[][3]) {
    glPushMatrix();
    listenToKeyboard(w);
    drawPyramid(p);
    glPopMatrix();
}

int main() {
    // some initialization
    ...codes...

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        renderPyramidWithInput(window, p);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);                      
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // other useful functions
    ...codes...
}
```

(I need to use the `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` to have multiple controllable objects, so here they are)

Comment: OpenGL is not a scene graph, OpenGL doesn't know objects, OpenGL just draws points, lines or triangles one at a time. glTranslate / glRotate, etc. (part of the old fixed function pipeline) do not manipulate objects, they just alter the transformation matrix that controls where on the screen things end up. glPushMatrix / glPopMatrix allows to build transformation hierarchies. Anything that's supposed to be persistent you need to store yourself. Also the fixed function pipeline is obsolete.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes I do understand that, but the problem is I know very little about these concepts like hierachies or pipelines. I tried to look at some docs by khronos like glRotate, but their descriptions are too complicated, yet my knowledge is too little. Anyway, if I should Google this what can be a question to start?

Comment: Google for "scene graphs". And try to change your mental model. Answer for yourself: Given only a pencil and a stack of sheets of paper, how would you keep track of things if you'd draw an animation by hand, frame-by-frame. Because ultimately that's all what OpenGL is: A very sophisticated pencil for drawing onto a digital canvas.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you for your help, I shall check that out : )

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL doesn't remember anything from one frame to another.

`glPushMatrix` saves the current rendering location (basically), `glPopMatrix` goes back to the saved location. It doesn't remember "oh, the last time I called drawPyramid the location was over there, I'd better use that location again". No, it just remembers the current location.

`glTranslatef` updates the current rendering location, but it starts from scratch every frame.

All this "rendering location" (a.k.a. matrix stack) stuff is to help you manage the locations of where you're drawing your objects, but it doesn't store anything for the next frame.

If you want to store the location of the pyramid, make a variable. Then, make it so the F key updates the variable. And when you render the pyramid, you get the position from the variable, and pass that position to glTranslatef.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work this out myself. Basically my codes are... fine, but they indeed need some improvement. The `listenToKeyboard` can be modified to:

```cpp
void listenToKeyboard(GLFWwindow* w) {
    if (glfwGetKey(w, GLFW_KEY_F) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        posArr[0] -= 0.1f;
    }

   ...other useful codes...
```

combined with a global array `posArr`

```cpp
// {deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ}
GLfloat posArr[3] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

which can be accessed in `renderPyramidWithInput`

```cpp
void renderPyramidWithInput(GLFWwindow* w, GLfloat p[][3]) {
    glPushMatrix();
    listenToKeyboard(w);
    glTranslatef(posArr[0], posArr[1], posArr[2]); // move in three directions;
    drawPyramid(p);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

As @datenwolf and @user253751 mentioned, OpenGL "does not remember anything", so reasonaly one may keep the positions and other desired data somewhere (here in `posArr`).

Similarly, one can define another array `angleArr` to store angles in a similar manner:

```cpp
// {xAngle, yAngle, zAngle}
GLfloat angleArr[3] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

and later access it using

```cpp
glRotatef(angleArr[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(angleArr[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(angleArr[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

These codes may not be the best solution (a good chance they are not), but at least they work in the way I'm expecting.

This is actually quite fundamental, but can be really frustrating if one doesn't meet the prerequisites, so... I left this here in case another learner found it useful.